# How to display other image when I scroll screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have two images in drawable. I am using the ImageView to display them. However, I want to display each image individually by hand. At the first, I want to display image1.png. When I scroll left to right, it will be display images image2.png. Could you suggest to me the way to do it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

you can use  ViewPager see this example http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: if you cant open link search in google this Using ViewPager for Screen Slides